# Meaning of this statement in R (Naive Bayes Classifier)

Tags: r, naivebayes

I am going through the code that our professor has provided us with, for creating a Naive Bayes Classifier.  Note that we are not using some built-in package; rather writing it ourselves for learning purposes.

One of the statements that the professor has used confuses me:

```
t = (Xtrain[,11] == c);
```

where `Xtrain` is the data set we are using to construct the classifier from.  I guess I understand what `Xtrain[,11] == c` does, but what I don't get is the assignment to `t`.  Could some one please let me know what it does and why?

Edit:

Following is the code that he is using to train the classifier:

```
X = read.csv("naive_bayes_binary.csv");
tnum = nrow(X)/2;  
Xtrain = X[1:tnum,];  # the data we construct the classifier from
p = matrix(0,3,10);  #  p[c,j] = P(x_j = 1 | Y = c)
prior = rep(0,3);  # will be prior probs
n = rep(0,3);  # will be class counts
for (c in 1:3) {
    t = (Xtrain[,11] == c);    ### What is this?
    n[c] = sum(t);
    for (j in 1:10) {
        p[c,j] = sum(Xtrain[t,j] == 1)/n[c]  
    # empirical prob that jth feat = 1 for cth class
    }
}
prior = n/tnum;  # the prior probabilities of the classes
```

Comment: does he reuse that t variable somewhere again?

Comment: @AlihanZıhna, yes he does.  I have updated the question.

Comment: `t`should be a vector of logicals indicating positions where `Xtrain[,11]` equals the class `c`. The sum of the vector gives you the number of occurrences which you then assign to `n`at the position of class `c`

Comment: @Val, thank you.  Please convert it into an answer and I will accept it.  I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, `t` is a vector of logicals, indicating the values equal to `c` in `X[,11]`. If you sum the vector `t` you'll get the number of occurrences (as `True` is `1` and `False` is `0`).

Here's a small working example:

```
## 10 classes
n <- rep(0,10)

# class number of interest
c <- 7

# data vector (in OP's example a column)
X11 <- sample(1:10,100,replace = T)

X11
      [1]  2  7  5 10  4  5  1  7  4  4  1  8  1  5  7  1 10  2  6  9 10  4  3  2  2  8  7 10  3  2  5  3 10  4  8  2  2  8  6  2  5  2
     [43]  1  4  9  3  3  4  9  7  5 10 10  9  6 10  9  8  7  9  8  2  1  1  4  5  3 10  4  9 10  3 10  1  7 10  6  8  3  1  9  5  5  2
     [85]  9  9  1  9  3  3  3 10  5  3  3  2  7  4  3 10


# vector of logicals
t <- X11 == c

t
  [1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [22] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [43] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [64] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [85] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE

# assign number of occurrences
n[c] <- sum(t)
```

The output of `n` shows 8 occurences:

```
n
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 8 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement `Xtrain[,11] == c` returns a boolean vector of TRUE or FALSE. The value in the vector will be TRUE if `Xtrain[,11]` equals the value `c` and 0 otherwise. This vector is then assigned to `t`.

So `t` may look like this:

```
FALSE
FALSE
TRUE
TRUE
FALSE
TRUE
```

or something. Again, the `TRUE` values occur when the corresponding row of `Xtrain[,11]` equals `c`, which is set in a loop to be 1, 2, or 3.

This variable `t` is apparently used later in the statement `n[c] = sum(t);`. When booleans are involved in arithmetic, they are implicitly converted to 1 (for TRUE) and 0 (for FALSE). So basically `n[c]` will contain the count of 1, 2, or 3 in the input `Xtrain[,11]`.

Here is a complete example. Suppose column 11 of Xtrain (`Xtrain[,11]`) looks like:

```
2
3
1
1
2
1
```

For c=1, `t` will look like:

```
FALSE
FALSE
TRUE
TRUE
FALSE
TRUE
```

so n[c] = 3.

For c=2, `t` will look like:

```
TRUE
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
TRUE
FALSE
```

so n[2] = 2.

For c=3, `t` will look like:

```
FALSE
TRUE
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
FALSE
```

so n[3] = 1.

Comment: You're thinking of C, not R.  R has a logical values.  So `Xtrain[,11] == c ` (and hence `t`) is a vector of TRUE or FALSE values.  However, when used in arithmetic, TRUE is converted to 1 and FALSE is converted to 0, so what you say about `n` is right.